# Retrieving part of a string which has many scenarios using T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need a T-SQL query to get an output (specified below under expected) covering all the cases. I tried doing that but was unsuccessful:

```
select 
    code,
    substring(code, patindex('%[0-9]%', code),
                    case 
                       when patindex('%[. ,/-]%', substring(code, patindex('%[0-9]%', code), len(code))) <> 0
                          then patindex('%[. ,/-]%', substring(code, patindex('%[0-9]%', code), len(code))) - 1 
                          else patindex('%[. ,/-]%', substring(code, patindex('%[0-9]%', code), len(code)))
                     end) 
from 
    table
```

This is expected output

```
input                           output 
------------------------------------------------------
AB 123456.123                   123456
AB 123456/123                   123456
AB 123456-123                   123456
AB B0-23456.123                 0-23456
AB 1234 5678 9545 3214.123      1234 5678 9545 3214
AB 123456 123                   123456 
AB.123456 123                   123456 
AB..123456 123                  123456 
AB..1C23456 123                 1C23456
```

Rules

1. Starts with the first occurrence of the number
2. Slice the string after special characters (, /.-) valid case
   2.1 if string has - after 3 numbers valid, eg: AB B0-23456.123 ----  0-23456
   2.2 if string has more than 3 numbers after a space valid, eg:AB 1234 5678 9545 3214.123 ---- 1234 5678 9545 3214

Comment: Seems like a problem with the schema. This should have been two separate columns from the beginning.

Comment: What are the rules here? This is too vague to get any solid rules from what I can see. What about something like A./XY39GH093-7734FD 8374 ABCD

Comment: @SeanLange 39GH093-7734 is the answer
rules 
1. Starts with the first occurence of the number
2.  slice the string after special characters(, /.-)
      valid case 
           --- if string has - after 3 numbers valid 
                             eg: AB B0-23456.123 ---- 0-23456
          ---- if string has more than 3 numbers after a space  valid
                          eg:AB 1234 5678 9545 3214.123 ---- 1234 5678 9545 3214

Comment: This is a nightmare!!! You should use a programming language and fix the data. Doing this in t-sql is not a good approach.

Comment: Python is upto the task. read up regular expression - 're'

Comment: Python is one choice, there are plenty of other languages out there. Choose one you know that can deal with regular expressions.

Comment: @SeanLange i need it in T-SQL (i do not have option)

Comment: Clarification is needed how does AB B0-23456.123 fit the exception of if a - appears after 3 numbers it is valid?  Did you mean if there are more than 3 numbers after the dash it is valid?

Comment: Two questions. 1 - Can you use CLR?  2 - Can you fix this horrible data during the process?

Comment: @ChadEstes in AB B0-23456.123  0 is the starting digit and from 0 to 6 i.e 0-23456 because after hiphen we have more than 3 numbers

Comment: @SeanLange 1. No
2. not understood

Comment: If you are being forced to parse stuff out of this it is an indication that your data structure is violating 1NF by shoving multiple values into a single tuple. Fixing that should be a priority. Doing this in pure t-sql is going to be horrific to say the least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this will meet all of your criteria, but do check it against edge cases not presented here to insure it does what you expect.

```
DECLARE @table as TABLE (code VARCHAR(40))

INSERT INTO @table
(code)
Values
('AB 123456.123'),
('AB 123456/123'),
('AB 123456-123'),
('AB B0-23456.123'),
('AB 1234 5678 954 3214.123'),
('AB 1234 5678 9545/3214.123'),
('AB 123456 123'),
('AB.123456 123'),
('AB..123456 123'),
('AB..1C23456 123')


SELECT 
code as [input],
SUBSTRING(code,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', code),
CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%[ -][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%',SUBSTRING(code,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', code),LEN(code))) <> 0
THEN 
    CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%[.,/]%',SUBSTRING(code,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', code),LEN(code))) < ISNULL(NULLIF(PATINDEX('%[ -][0-9][0-9][0-9][^0-9]%',SUBSTRING(code,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', code),LEN(code))),0),LEN(code))
    THEN PATINDEX('%[.,/]%',SUBSTRING(code,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', code),LEN(code)))-1
    ELSE ISNULL(NULLIF(PATINDEX('%[ -][0-9][0-9][0-9][^0-9]%',SUBSTRING(code,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', code),LEN(code))),0),LEN(code))
    END
ELSE PATINDEX('%[. ,/-]%', SUBSTRING(code,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', code),LEN(code)))-1
END
) as [output]
FROM @table
```

EDIT: Modification to inner case statement to correct for edge case mentioned in comments, just to prove that this could be done without using a CTE. :)

Comment: yes it worked for the above sample data but 2.2 rule has broken eg:AB 1234 5678 954 3214-12345.123   -----     expected: 1234 5678 ---- output of your query is  1234 5678 954    .rest are fine. Thanks for the effort

Comment: @Vman code above was updated to take care of the example you provided of a failed use case.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest: This is a nightmare. `T-SQL` is absolutely the wrong tool for this!

Just because I placed an insufficient (due to your insufficient question) answer, I'm urged to solve this somehow. That's a matter of sportsmanship...

```
DECLARE @mockup TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY, YourString VARCHAR(1000));
INSERT INTO @mockup VALUES
 ('AB 123456.123')                 
,('AB 123456/123')                 
,('AB 123456-123')                 
,('AB B0-23456.123')               
,('AB 1234 5678 9545 3214.123')    
,('AB 123456 123')                 
,('AB.123456 123')                 
,('AB..123456 123')                
,('AB..1C23456 123')
,('AB 1234 5678 954 3214-12345.123');
```

--The nightmare

```sql
WITH CutForRules AS
(
    SELECT t.ID
          ,t.YourString
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t.ID ORDER BY (SELECT (NULL))) FragmentIndex
          ,c AsXml
          ,d.value('text()[1]','varchar(100)') Fragment
          ,ISNUMERIC(d.value('text()[1]','varchar(100)')) FragmentIsNum
          ,LEN(d.value('text()[1]','varchar(100)')) FragmentLength
          ,d.value('@dlmt','varchar(10)') Delimiter
    FROM @mockup t
    CROSS APPLY(SELECT REVERSE(SUBSTRING(t.YourString,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',t.YourString),1000))) A(a) 
    CROSS APPLY(SELECT REVERSE(SUBSTRING(a,PATINDEX('%[ /.-]%',a)+1,1000))) B(b)    
    CROSS APPLY(SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(b,'/','|'),' ','</x><x dlmt=" ">'),'.','</x><x dlmt=".">'),'-','</x><x dlmt="-">'),'|','</x><x dlmt="/">') + '</x>' AS XML)) C(c)
    CROSS APPLY c.nodes('/x') D(d)
)
SELECT t1.ID
      ,t1.YourString
      ,(
        SELECT CONCAT(t2.Delimiter,t2.Fragment)
        FROM CutForRules t2
        WHERE t1.ID=t2.ID
          AND (t2.FragmentIndex<(SELECT MIN(t3.FragmentIndex) 
                                 FROM CutForRules t3 
                                 WHERE t3.ID=t1.ID
                                   AND t3.FragmentIndex>t2.FragmentIndex
                                   AND t3.Delimiter=' '
                                   AND t3.FragmentLength<4
                                   AND t3.FragmentIsNum=1)
               OR NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM CutForRules t4 WHERE t4.ID=t1.ID AND t4.Delimiter=' ' AND t4.FragmentLength<4)
              )
        ORDER BY t2.FragmentIndex
        FOR XML PATH('')
       )
FROM CutForRules t1
GROUP BY t1.ID,t1.YourString
ORDER BY t1.ID;
```

You might place a `SELECT * FROM CutForRules` to see the intermediate resultset I use for this.

But I'm pretty sure, that you'll come up with *Oh yeah, that's working, but there is one more case...*

Just to get this clear: I'm out at this point ;-)

### UPDATE: Some explanation

The cte *CutForRules* will return this set for my test-data:

```
+----+---------------------------------+---------+---+---+------+
|    | YourString                      |Fragment | N | L | Delm |
+----+---------------------------------+---------+---+---+------+
| 1  | AB 123456.123                   | 123456  | 1 | 6 | NULL |
+----+---------------------------------+---------+---+---+------+
| 2  | AB 123456/123                   | 123456  | 1 | 6 | NULL |
+----+---------------------------------+---------+---+---+------+
| 3  | AB 123456-123                   | 123456  | 1 | 6 | NULL |
+----+---------------------------------+---------+---+---+------+
| 4  | AB B0-23456.123                 | 0       | 1 | 1 | NULL |
+----+---------------------------------+---------+---+---+------+
| 4  | AB B0-23456.123                 | 23456   | 1 | 5 | -    |
+----+---------------------------------+---------+---+---+------+
| 5  | AB 1234 5678 9545 3214.123      | 1234    | 1 | 4 | NULL |
+----+---------------------------------+---------+---+---+------+
| 5  | AB 1234 5678 9545 3214.123      | 5678    | 1 | 4 |      |
+----+---------------------------------+---------+---+---+------+
| 5  | AB 1234 5678 9545 3214.123      | 9545    | 1 | 4 |      |
+----+---------------------------------+---------+---+---+------+
| 5  | AB 1234 5678 9545 3214.123      | 3214    | 1 | 4 |      |
+----+---------------------------------+---------+---+---+------+
| 6  | AB 123456 123                   | 123456  | 1 | 6 | NULL |
+----+---------------------------------+---------+---+---+------+
| 7  | AB.123456 123                   | 123456  | 1 | 6 | NULL |
+----+---------------------------------+---------+---+---+------+
| 8  | AB..123456 123                  | 123456  | 1 | 6 | NULL |
+----+---------------------------------+---------+---+---+------+
| 9  | AB..1C23456 123                 | 1C23456 | 0 | 7 | NULL |
+----+---------------------------------+---------+---+---+------+
| 10 | AB 1234 5678 954 3214-12345.123 | 1234    | 1 | 4 | NULL |
+----+---------------------------------+---------+---+---+------+
| 10 | AB 1234 5678 954 3214-12345.123 | 5678    | 1 | 4 |      |
+----+---------------------------------+---------+---+---+------+
| 10 | AB 1234 5678 954 3214-12345.123 | 954     | 1 | 3 |      |
+----+---------------------------------+---------+---+---+------+
| 10 | AB 1234 5678 954 3214-12345.123 | 3214    | 1 | 4 |      |
+----+---------------------------------+---------+---+---+------+
| 10 | AB 1234 5678 954 3214-12345.123 | 12345   | 1 | 5 | -    |
+----+---------------------------------+---------+---+---+------+
```

The provided `SELECT` will group this by `ID,YourString`. That means: 1 row per ID.

The returned columns are the grouping columns plus a big computed one.

This is a *correlated sub-query*. It will fetch all rows for the current ID and process them. And its result is returned `FOR XML PATH`, which is a trick to concatenate all the results.

The tricky part is in the `WHERE`: If there is at least one numeric fragment after a blank with a length `<4`, the string will not include this and all following fragments.

How do I get the *element before the current element*?

This is again a *correlated sub-query* fetching the element within the ID-group with a `FragmentIndex` bigger than the current one.

Comment: yes it worked for the above sample data but 2.2 rule has broken eg:AB 1234 5678 954 3214-12345.123 ----- expected: 1234 5678 ---- output of your query is 1234 5678 954 .rest are fine. Thanks for the effort

Comment: i understood the idea. but i need the query to meet the criteria.Thanks

Comment: finally nightmare worked with all my scenarios. but i need the idea of the implementation. Could you please update the idea? Thanks a lot

Comment: Thanks a lot again @shnugo

Comment: sorry i missed that. Accepted the answer and voted up